# python function compression

Tags: python, python-2.6

I have written this big function to do some formatting in my python code. Would you be able to suggest anyways to make this smaller ?

```
def disfun(String1,String2,String3):
        if String3 == "A" or String3 == "B":
            if String3 == "A":
                pass
            elif String3 == "B":
                print "#"*54

            print "##"," "*48,"##"
            print "##",'{0:^48}'.format(String2),"##"
            print "##",'{0:^48}'.format(String1),"##"
            print "##"," "*48,"##"
            print "#"*54

        elif String3 == "C":
            print "-"*40
            print "--",'{0:^34}'.format(String2),"--"
            print "-"*40

        elif String3 == 'D':
            String2 = ' * '.join(String2)
            print "#"*54
            print "##",'{0:^48}'.format(String2),"##"
            print "##",'{0:^48}'.format(String1),"##"
            print "#"*54

        elif String3 == 'E':
           print "*"*54
           print "**",'{0:^48}'.format(String2),"**"
           print "**",'{0:^48}'.format(String1),"**"
           print "*"*54
```

Comment: I'm confused, you never even defined the variable "string"

Comment: `string` can be a global variable (not a good name, because of the standard `string` module, though).

Comment: When you edit the original posted code in response to an answer so that an answer no longer make sense, it *really* confuses people who come along in the future.

Comment: Updated the code. Apologies, there were typos in the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if String3 == "A":
    pass
elif String3 == "B":
    print "#"*54
```

can easily become...

```
if String3 == "B":
    print "#"*54
```

---

Also, there's a bunch of shared code between B, D, and E:

```
def disfun(String1,String2,String3):

    if String3 in ("B", "D", "E"):
        print "#"*54

        if String3 == "B":
            print "##"," "*48,"##"

        if String2 == "D":
            String2 = ' * '.join(String2)

        print "##",'{0:^48}'.format(String2),"##"
        print "##",'{0:^48}'.format(String1),"##"
        print "##"," "*48,"##"
        print "#"*54

    elif String3 == "C":
        print "-"*40
        print "--",'{0:^34}'.format(String2),"--"
        print "-"*40
```

Comment: True have reduced the code from 5 different function I had written previously . Missed that out . Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I'd try to reduce all the formatting to one call:

```
def marquee (width,  *content, headerCharacter = '#'):
   print headerCharacter  * width
   for item in content:
       print "%s%s%s" % (headerCharacter * 2, content.center(width - 4), headerCharacter * 2)
   print headerCharacter  * width
```

And then change all the logic so it simply picks the right *content (looks like you have one or two items depending on code path)  and header character